# Acessing dictionary from numpy savez

Tags: python, numpy

Given two set of `dict` saved using numpy `savez` as below

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import load
names=['t1','t2','t3']
arr_name = np.array(names)
arr_val = np.array([1,2,3])


np.savez('data.npz', dict_one=dict(fone=arr_name,nval=arr_val),
         dict_two=dict(fone=arr_name,nval=arr_val))
```

When reload the data as

```
dict_data = load('data.npz',allow_pickle=True)
ndata=dict_data['dict_one']
opt=ndata['fone']
```

The compiler return an error

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

May I know what is the issue here,and whether this is a good practice of saving multiple `dict` with numpy arrays in it?

The output for `print(ndata)`

```
{'fone': array(['t1', 't2', 't3'], dtype='<U2'), 'nval': array([1, 2, 3])}
```

The output for `print(dict_data )`

```
<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7fe8887c6850>
```

Spec:

```
numpy 1.21.1 and Python 3.9.
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(ndata)`?

Comment: @balandongiv.  `data` != `ndata`

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I'm unable to reproduce based on the information provided

Comment: I actually reproduced this on Python 3.9.5, NumPy 1.20.3. For some reason, `type(ndata)` is `numpy.ndarray`, not `dict`...

Comment: Did you have a stray `ndata` in the workspace before loading

Comment: @balandongiv. Savez us not saving arbitrary data. Load interprets all zip entries as the binary data of an array. You are reading in garbage

Comment: @balandongiv. Insufficient understanding on my part. Can you print `dict_data`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, [here's a MCVE](https://tio.run/##hZAxb8MgEIV3fgWbQUJRE88s3Tp1yWZF1inGKgoGBJdE9M87gHHUrQzo0PvevSd8wh9n@3Wdg1uodlQv3gWknwlV/Pom7Wnvi08UIrWeEAuLinLo8NiJDk/l6rsLgRDGIlGZqUN@QWIV5VV6gPmrDEdxEv2FEzJrUzwtkXGSmQgP9cuKIuikrzg6q2QZ2FymPUrYvFW27VwQup/qwaf719PyD1GpG/vgpBonQNi6GgdTqwHGuOfo9fVmlDyHu8pFCyjflqHbq@bf8EFbZJUQFJNX25wDnUdpN36u7Lq@AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @MadPhysicist, please see update

Comment: @balandongiv. Try `ndata=ndata.item()`. I think I can draft an answer now

Comment: @ForceBru. I'm on mobile, so that's doubly appreciated. The output string was confusing me at first

Comment: Does this sound like a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17912878/2988730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says you can't index an array with a string like 'fone'.

`savez` saves arrays, you gave it dicts.  It has wrapped each dict in the 1 element object dtype array:

```
In [296]: names=['t1','t2','t3']
     ...: arr_name = np.array(names)
     ...: arr_val = np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: np.savez('data.npz', dict_one=dict(fone=arr_name,nval=arr_val),
     ...:          dict_two=dict(fone=arr_name,nval=arr_val))

In [298]: dict_data = np.load('data.npz',allow_pickle=True)
     ...: ndata=dict_data['dict_one']
In [299]: ndata
Out[299]: 
array({'fone': array(['t1', 't2', 't3'], dtype='<U2'), 'nval': array([1, 2, 3])},
      dtype=object)
```

Use `item` (or indexing) to extract the element from the array

```
In [300]: ndata.item()
Out[300]: {'fone': array(['t1', 't2', 't3'], dtype='<U2'), 'nval': array([1, 2, 3])}
In [301]: ndata.item()['fone']
Out[301]: array(['t1', 't2', 't3'], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but wasted my close vote: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17912878/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes, I recently wrote a similar answer to another SO.

Comment: An overlapping question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842969/call-array-with-keyword-argument-from-npz-in-numpy.  Not quite a duplicate, but part of my answer uses this `item()` trick.